# Optimizing Hibernate session.createQuery().list();

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, query-optimization, pojo

We have a Users table (MySQL) with 120,000 rows

```
List<User> users = session.createQuery("from User").list();
```

This hibernate query takes about 6 to 9 seconds to execute. How can we optimize this? Is MySQL the bottleneck? Or is `.list()` usually this slow?

Comment: Where you will display result?

Comment: @Masud, the results will not be displayed. we need the result set for some processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ofcourse it's slow because the query perform the full table scan. You should join other objects associated with it, including `where` clause of the query, the query could be changed to return the limited number of records or use criteria API and projection.

Comment: unfortunately we need to the entire table. so we can't use the criteria API or projection or WHERE clause

Comment: then you have no choice

Comment: Is mySQL the bottleneck? Or the CPU which is running tomcat? or the memory?

Comment: then what is causing it to be so slow?

Answer (score 1):

Use pagination on your query. You should not call all rows at a time. You can set first position of result and maximum result. For example, if you want to read first 100 result than change your query like:

```
Query q=session.createQuery("from User");
q.setFirstResult(fistRes);// this will variable
q.setMaxResults(maxRes);// this will also be variable as parameter.
```

Comment: @SaqibAli This will partition your result into different page.